# Changing strings into integers

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm going crazy and I can not figure the right solution :(

How can I solve that problems. I have a loop and I can get diffrent types like:

```
empty string
10
10K
2.3K
2.34K
2M
2.2M
2.23M
```

I need to change them into numbers:

```
0
10
10000
2300
2340
2000000
2200000
2230000
```

Comment: is this homework? you should say so in the question.

Comment: can you post your desired output? is it 10K to be converted to 10000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your steps should be:

- check if string is empty

  - return 0
- check if string ends in K or M

  - if it does, strip that character off the end, store it for later
  - multiply by appropriate factor (K = 1000 or M = 1000000)

This can be achieved with the following:

```
def convert(value):
    if value:
        # determine multiplier
        multiplier = 1
        if value.endswith('K'):
            multiplier = 1000
            value = value[0:len(value)-1] # strip multiplier character
        elif value.endswith('M'):
            multiplier = 1000000
            value = value[0:len(value)-1] # strip multiplier character

        # convert value to float, multiply, then convert the result to int
        return int(float(value) * multiplier)

    else:
        return 0

values = [
    '',
    '10',
    '10K',
    '2.3K',
    '2.34K',
    '2M',
    '2.2M',
    '2.23M',
]

# use a list comprehension to call the function on all values
numbers = [convert(value) for value in values]

print numbers
```

This should return

```
[0, 10, 10000, 2300, 2340, 2000000, 2200000, 2230000]
```

Comment: I got this error with your solution ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10K' :(

Comment: You are using the `return` keyword but not inside a function

Comment: @AnnaK I forgot to strip the K and M off the end of the string if they're present. Updating answer...

Comment: Soviut I'm getting that error line 13, in convert
    number = int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10K'
Could you help me please?

Comment: @AnnaK I also realized that no distinction needs to be made between floats and ints since they'll all be integers in the end. I've updated the code accordingly.

Comment: 2.3456K should be 2345.6 which is a float, not an int.

Comment: @NehalJWani that value isn't present in any of the examples the OP gave. Don't invent edge cases the OP doesn't have.

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ No harm in covering them :-)

Comment: The harm is that it would complicate the answer. It's not in scope.

Comment: Soviut Im so sorry but my English is so bad. I wanted to get from fe 10.23K = 10230. Could you please help me? I have been trying to solve it for 3 days :(

Comment: @AnnaK my mistake, there was a typo, I spelled "multiplier" wrong in the check for the string ending in K. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A quick hack to get the floats:

```
In [15]: powers = {'K': 10 ** 3, 'M': 10 ** 6}

In [16]: def f(s):
    ...:     try:
    ...:         if s[-1] in powers.keys():
    ...:            return float(s[:-1]) * powers[s[-1]]
    ...:         else:
    ...:            return float(s)
    ...:     except:
    ...:         return s
    ...:         

In [17]: map(f, ['', '10', '10K', '2.3K', '2.34K', '2M', '2.2M', '2.23M'])
Out[17]: ['', 10.0, 10000.0, 2300.0, 2340.0, 2000000.0, 2200000.0, 2230000.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with other answers, this solution will be best to solve it without Regular Expression.

But, if you still want to use regex, here is a nice way to do this using JavaScript (sorry, not familiar with Python):

```
var new_arr = ['','10','10K','2.3K','2.34K','2M','2.2M','2.23M'].map(function(value) {
    return value.replace(/^(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)([kgm]?)$/i, function(_, number, group) {
        return !group && (number||'0') || parseFloat(number) * Math.pow(10, {'k':3,'m':6,'g':9}[group.toLowerCase()]);
    });
});
```

If someone could translate it to Python, it would be best (and it will teach me a bit of Python well). :))